# How Do I Get My Installable Trigger to Run Once and Not Twice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a simple onEdit script that can run longer than 30 seconds, depending on what I am doing on my spreadsheet and in some cases, I need this to happen.

I understand, if I do not use an installable trigger in this case, that the simple onedit script will time out. So I now have a simple onEdit trigger and installable onEdit trigger that can run at the same time.

But here is my problem. I mentioned that I need my script to run longer than 30 seconds sometimes. But if I use an installable trigger, in conjunction with the simple trigger, the onEdit function will begin to cause the changes that do not require 30 seconds of run time to fire twice and I don’t want this to happen.

Incidentally, if I do not use an installable trigger and only use the simple trigger, the changes that do not require 30 seconds of run time fire once and do as I need. But then the changes that require 30 seconds of run time times out, incompleting the tasks that I need done.

So how do I get the installable trigger to run the changes needed under 30 seconds once, while still giving me the ability to run changes longer than 30 seconds when needed?

Comment: Why do the changes take 30 seconds specifically, are you able to speed those up at all?

Comment: Hi @ross! That's a great question. It would be nice if I could write something in the code that could speed up the run time. But as I look at what I have now, I can't eliminate or simplify anything in that particular section because the script is rebooting all of the cells that were changed and bringing them back to their original formation.

Comment: Hey @Ross! I want to thank you again for your question. I am reconsidering how I am doing somethings in my script and I already see some possibilities. So thank you for that. But meanwhile, if anyone has an answer to my question here, feel free to reply. Someone else may find this post useful.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include the code for your scripts and Execution Transcripts as well? Would you please clarify the name of your installable script? May I also suggest that you re-read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); it will explain why you need to some detailed information so that people can better understand your problem, and hopefully provide helpful answers rather than not respond to your question because it might be poorly understood.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about that the simple triggers cannot run for longer than 30 seconds, while the installable ones do.

> So, why do you not user **ONLY the installable trigger** without the
>   simple one. You can bind it to any desired function, it doesn't need
>   to be called `onEdit()`.

Comment: Nice! If I need this, I will definitely consider this functionality. Thank you for your input!